# Storing Names of linux pkges

Tags: linux, command-line, package-management, flatpak

This command does not contain flatpack or snap packages:

```
pacman -Qqe > pkglist.txt
```

I need a mass command to store all package names in a single text file

OS: Arch Linux

Comment: Have you tried expac https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=expac ?

Answer (score 4):

> This command does not contain flatpack or snap packages:

Nor does it contain things installed via `pip`, `conda`, containers downloaded using `docker` or `podman`, packages from `cargo` or `npm` or …

I don't think there's a single command to do what you want: in the end, you've got a lot of packages manager that work in "parallel" to your distro's packaging, and it's impossible for a system to know which things you consider "packages you want to save" (as you seem to do with flatpacks and snaps) or things that are not.

Since that list is also only useful together with the tools to understand (and potentially install) its members, I'd go with: you'll want separate lists for all of these, anyways.